# Resizing a square image to a rectangle with a fixed aspect ratio

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, batch-processing, photoshop-scripting, crop

I have a very large batch of images that I need to resize. I am new to Photoshop (have used Elements for years) and I am unsure how to do this.  Basically, all the images are currently 2000 x 2000. They are product silhouettes so the item is in the middle, surrounded by white space. I need to resize them to 1768 x 2160 and keep an aspect ratio of 140 x 171.

Is there any way to do this. If so, step by step directions would be amazing! I don't want to make any errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished with an *Action* which can be applied to a batch of images.

- Make a source folder with only the original images and an empty destination folder for the finished images.
- Open one of the original images in Photoshop.
- Open the *Actions* panel and create a folder for your action using the *Create new set* button in the bottom.
- Click the *Create new action* button and choose the set you just created as *Set*. Click the *Record* button to start recording the action.
- Resize the image to 1768 x 1768 px, using *Image > Image Size* with *Resample Image* turned on.
- Extend the canvas to 1768 x 2160 px, using *Image > Canvas Size*, set *Canvas extension color* to *White*.
- Use the *Stop playing/recording* button in the *Actions* panel to stop recording. Your action should look something like this:

  [image]
- Close the image without saving.
- Now where are ready for batching. Choose *File > Automate > Batch*.
- The *Batch* dialogue could be setup as I did here:

  [image]
- Choose the set and action you just created. Choose the proper source and destination folder. Suppress dialogs and warnings.
- File naming can be done in many ways. Here I've chosen to have the original filename followed by "_1768x2160" and the extension.
- Click *OK* and Photoshop should start processing your source images.

Comment: Awesome!  That worked PERFECTLY!!!!  Thank you so much.  You saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Is there a script that could be added to "fit" the image into the frame?  Some of the items are very small in the frame and would need to be resized to be larger.  Again we are talking about large quantities of images so a batch process would be excellent.

Comment: You don't need a script for this. Just add _Image > Trim_ as the first step of the action to remove white space before scaling. (If you like the answer, please accept it).